# pyspark -convert structure to float

Tags: pyspark

> so i am using crawler to import a data and bu mistake its assuming some columns that are only number are structure
> I am trying to convert them to float using the below code but it doesnt work
> any suggestion?

```
for a_dftype in changedTypedf.dtypes[2:]:
  col_name = a_dftype[0]
  col_type = a_dftype[1]
  if col_type == 'struct':
    changedTypedf = changedTypedf.withColumn(col_name,changedTypedf[col_name].cast(FloatType()))
#   #print(col_name)
```

Comment: Please include your input and expected output as part of your question stem.